# Display items from JSON server response

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have this JSON returned from the server:

```
[
   {
      "symbol":"one option"
   },
   {
      "symbol":"second option"
   }
   .......
]
```

I tried to display the data into dropdown using:

```
<Select value={props.selectedData}>
  {props.availableData.map((option) => (
  <option value={option.symbol}>{option.symbol}</option>
  ))}
</Select>
```

But the list if empty.
What is the proper way to display the data?

Comment: Please share code related to getting data from server and also how you pass the props.

Comment: Youre doing in the proper way, look into other part of code, maybe you've done mistake there.

Comment: what is that `Select` component? from `react-select`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to just put the ternary operator condition you have both ways

1.

```
{
props.availableData ?
<Select                            
    value={props.selectedData}>
    {props.availableData.map((option) => (
        <option value={option.symbol}>{option.symbol}</option>
    ))}
</Select>:null
}
```

2. 

```
{
props.availableData.length === 0 ?
<Select                            
    value={props.selectedData}>
    {props.availableData.map((option) => (
        <option value={option.symbol}>{option.symbol}</option>
    ))}
</Select>:null  
}
```